# deploy a WAR with plan.xml using WLST

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c, wlst

I am deploying a WAR file to Weblogic 12c with a `plan.xml`. My environment runs on three different host machines:

- `admin-server` host
- `managed-server-1` host
- `managed-server-2` host

The deployment is done and Weblogic shows on the `Console` the path to the `deployment plan` file. But this path is only valid on the `admin-server` host:

```
/home/oracle/bin/hello-world/plan.xml
```

For me, it seems that `plan.xml` is not used by the application.

I deploy the artifact from the `admin-server` host. Before the deployment, I copy the *.war and `plan.xml` to the `admin-server` disk and I use WLST to deploy to the Cluster.

But I am uncertain whether I need to copy the plan.xml file to the managed-server hosts under the same path that Weblogic shows on the console.

Or the Weblogic `admin-server` will copy the deployment plan file automatically to all managed servers?

How does this work?
Do I need to copy manually the XML to the managed server or not?